# Using .load in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am using `.load()` function in JavaScript and I'm working with JSP java files. I am loading a page like this in JavaScript

```
$("#body").load("livestatus #status")
```

The problem is the div I'm trying to load doesn't load immediately on page load because it contains some data from APIs, so there's a one second delay but my code doesn't accommodate that delay.

Comment: Just to clarify, while jQuery is a JavaScript library, `.load` is a jQuery method, not a JavaScript method

Comment: you're right, my bad

Comment: What is the problem? Do you just want a loading indicator?

Comment: can you help fix the jQuery issue

Comment: No, i don't just want a loading indicator. i need to add a delay so all my neccesary resources would have loaded in the div before a .load method is fully invoked

Comment: I think you want some scripts on `livestatus` to run before you extract the contents of `#status`.  I’m not 100% sure, but I don’t think that will work.  You might be able to use `.load`’s optional callback parameter to manipulate your loaded content

Comment: I'm rendering some information on #status so there's a bit of a delay and .load doesn't accommodate that delay

Comment: What does *"rendering some information on #status"* mean exactly? If that is server side then something is wrong there. load()  will wait for data to arrive but if you start sending before it is ready it is a server side issue

Comment: the requests are being made at the backend with spring MVC and sent to a jsp that renders it onto a div. the funny thing is when i render the whole page everything acts normally. but when i target a specific div it doesn't capture the responses gotten from the request

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code in document.ready block or if you are making an ajax request then put your code in Ajax success function

Comment: how can you accommodate that with a .load function. A .load functions loads a section of the page afresh

Comment: The div which you are trying to load must be initially making some Ajax request to gets its data from API??

Comment: the requests are being made at the backend with spring MVC and sent to a jsp that renders it onto a div

Comment: Ok in that case write your jQuery load code in the jsp itself wrapped in script tag at end of jsp file..so that load function will execute only after your rendering part is done

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery and it just not initialized for some element, you can use

```
$(function() {
    $("#body"). // ... your code
});
```

If it calls through some time and you can't track when exactly, you can use live listeners on some event. Like, click on this element.

```
$("body").on("click", "#body", function() {
    // your code
});
```

$("body") can contain any parent element which had loaded before jQuery.

Or you can load 1px image with you code which loads after main code and track when it will load.

```
<div id="body">
    <!-- your markup -->
    <img class="loading-status-img" src="../path_to_1px_small_image.png" style="display:none">
    <img class="loading-status-img-2" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQI12NgYAAAAAMAASDVlMcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="display:none">
    <!-- your markup -->
</div>

<script>
    $("body").on("load", ".loading-status-img", function() {
        // execute you code here after #body will load
    });
</script>
```

The second image is encoded with base64.

[UPD] old version of jQuery have another syntax. More: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I'm loading a portion from another page, so i have to call the url of that page first

Comment: Live listeners work for all elements by defined selectors on the page without depending when it appeared on the page. So, they will work for your content from another page immediately after you will load HTML to DOM. Try it.